# In which file do I set a key in react native async storage for the first time the app starts?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am developing a react native app and I would like data persistence. Async storage is working fine as I expect it to, however the problem is that I initialize a key 'servers' in a component and and call the setItem function in componentDidMount function. Now because of this every time I terminate the app and run it again all the data from the previous session is removed as the 'servers' key is reset when the component is mounted. I understand why this is causing the problem so I want to know where should I set the key in my code that it will not reset on every time my component mounts.

This is the function that I call in componentDidMount. This is the only way to declare a key in Async storage correct? because without it I would not be able to call getItem.

```
const save = async () => {
  try {
    server_list = await AsyncStorage.setItem('server_list', JSON.stringify({servers: []}));
  }
  catch (e){
    console.log("Failed to load")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by filling the AsyncStorage only as long as there is no data under the server_list key.

This would look like this:

```
setServerList = async (value) => {
  try {
      const serverList = await AsyncStorage.getItem('server_list');
      if(serverList === null) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('server_list', value)
      }
  } catch(e) {
    // save error
  }
  console.log('Done.')
}
```

You can still call this in the componentDidMount and your server list will no longer be overwritten